# Word templates populated automatically from list fields from a SharePoint custom list?

Tags: list, templates, sharepoint, ms-word, workflow

Is it possible to automatically create Word documents which include list fields from a custom SharePoint list?

here is the scenario: - custom list (over 100 columns) - Word templates (not sure where is best to store them yet) - Entry Form will provide data for the templates (or partial data, ie Client name, Sales Rep) - a form that will have buttons (ie 'Create Order Form', 'Create PO')

the idea is to be able to generate partial populated templates from a custom list with a puch of a button.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to sound like a commercial :) but the company I work for has a product that allows you to do that: [OfficeWriter SharePoint integration](http://officewriter.softartisans.com/default.aspx?pageid=434) and in specific the [SharePoint developers section](http://officewriter.softartisans.com/officewriter-439.aspx). You can see some samples in there of similar things.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

sure you want it in Word?, Excel is more often misused for this (make some connection i tihnk odbc or so).